# Detectar USB en C#

Tags: c#

Necesito mostrar los *USB* conectados a mi computadora y que tanto al desconectar el *USB* como ponerlo, se quite o se ponga la letra del *USB* correspondiente en un *ComboBox*. Lo quiero hacer en *C#*, tengo este código pero está en *Visual Basic*.

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef M As System.Windows.Forms.Message)'
        'These are the required subclassing codes for detecting device based removal and arrival.
    '

If M.Msg = WM_DEVICECHANGE Then
Select M.WParam
    '
    'Check if a device was added. 
    Case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL

        Dim DevType As Integer = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadInt32(M.LParam, 4)

        If DevType = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME Then

            Dim Vol As New DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME

            Vol = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(M.LParam, GetType(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME))

        If Vol.Dbcv_Flags = 0 Then

            For i As Integer = 0 To 20

                If Math.Pow(2, i) = Vol.Dbcv_Unitmask Then
                        Dim usb = From getInfo In System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives
                        Dim d As IO.DriveInfo
                        For Each d In usb
                            If d.IsReady = True AndAlso d.DriveType = IO.DriveType.Removable Then
                                unidades.Items.Add(d.Name & d.VolumeLabel).ToString()
                            End If
                        Next
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
```

... y tengo este código para detectar el remover el *USB*, pero no se me remueve del *ComboBox*, no sé por qué.

```
    Case DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE

        Dim DevType As Integer = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadInt32(M.LParam, 4)

        If DevType = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME Then

            Dim Vol As New DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME

            Vol = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(M.LParam, GetType(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME))

            If Vol.Dbcv_Flags = 0 Then

                For i As Integer = 0 To 20

                    If Math.Pow(2, i) = Vol.Dbcv_Unitmask Then

                        Dim usb = From getInfo In System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives
                        Dim d As IO.DriveInfo
                        For Each d In usb
                            If d.IsReady = False AndAlso d.DriveType = IO.DriveType.Removable Then
                                unidades.Items.Remove(d.Name & d.VolumeLabel & usb.ToString)
                            End If
                        Next
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
End Select
End If

MyBase.WndProc(M)
```

Comment: Prueba como solución sencilla un botón de "Actualizar" en la que vuelva detectar los USB. Si funciona puedes encapsular la detección en un hilo paralelo en ejecución de manera asíncrona para actualizar el listado del combo.

Comment: Mira [este proyecto](https://code.google.com/archive/p/usb-devices-list/downloads), lista los USB conectados y los guarda en un archivo

Comment: muchas gracias MainMind eres de gran ayuda.

Comment: ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez un poco tarde yo ya lo tenia implementado asi dentro de un form:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    refreshUsb();
}
const int WM_DEVICECHANGE = 537;
const int DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000;
const int DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = 0x8004;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_DEVICECHANGE&&((int)m.WParam==DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL ||(int)m.WParam==DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE ))            
        refreshUsb();

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}

private void refreshUsb()
{
    var usbs = System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(d => d.DriveType == System.IO.DriveType.Removable).ToArray();
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
    comboBox1.Items.AddRange(usbs);
}
```

Comment: Gracias Rolando servira de algo tu ayuda!

Comment: @Rolando y se podra detectar en una web ?

Comment: @PieroDev pero como que en una web?

Comment: @RolandoCorratgeNieves como tu detectar en window form no se si se podra detectar pero en versión web.

Comment: @PieroDev eso viola la seguridad del lado del cliente

Comment: @RolandoCorratgeNieves se podra detectar una huella digital con web c# ?